# Finding Fixed Field (Involving Nonreal Complex Number)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

The problem:

> Let $\omega$ be a nonreal complex number such that $\omega^5=1$ and let $\phi$ be the automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ with $\phi(\omega) = \omega^4$. Find the fixed field of $<\phi>$.

My attempt thus far:
First, $\mathbb{Q}$($\omega)$ = {$a+b\omega+c\omega^2+d\omega^3+e\omega^4 | a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$}.

And based on the given automorphism, we know:

$\phi(\omega^2)$ = $\omega^3$, 
$\phi(\omega^3)$ = $\omega^2$,
$\phi(\omega^4)$ = $\omega$

Hence, $\phi(a+b\omega+c\omega^2+d\omega^3+e\omega^4)$ = $a+e\omega+d\omega^2+c\omega^3+b\omega^4$. If $b = e$ and $d=c$, it will be fixed.

Now consider $\omega + \omega^4 \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. $(\omega + \omega^4)^2$ = $\omega^8 + \omega^5 + \omega^5 + \omega^2$ = $\omega^3 + \omega^2 + 2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$

and also consider $0 = 1 + \omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4 = 1 + (\omega + \omega^4) + (\omega^2 + \omega^3) = -1 + (\omega + \omega^4) + (\omega + \omega^4)^2$.

Applying the quadratic formula yields $(\omega + \omega^4) = \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and $(\omega + \omega^4) = \frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}$

This is where I'm getting stuck on how to proceed. Any help on what to do next, as well as feedback/corrections/comments on what I've done so far, would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct. A quicker way might be to use a bit of Galois theory:

The Galois group of $\mathbf{Q}(\omega)$ is $(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times$ of order $4$. The order of $\sigma:\omega\mapsto \omega^{4}=\omega^{-1}$ is $2$, so the degree of the fixed field $\mathbf{Q}(\omega)^{\langle \sigma\rangle}$ is $2$ by Galois theory.

The element $\omega+\omega^{-1}=2\cos \frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is clearly invariant under $\sigma$, so we have $\color{red}{\mathbf{Q}(\omega)^{\langle \sigma\rangle}=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{5})}$.

Comment: This makes sense - thank you! My last question would how you obtained $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ from the value of $\omega + \omega^{-1}$. Wouldn't that instead show that the fixed field of $\phi$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\omega + \omega^{-1})$?

Comment: We simply have $\mathbf{Q}(\omega+\omega^{-1})=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.